# PySpark group data into chunks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data which has 2 columns like below. Basically I want to group the data in segments (say 1000 entries) and create new features from the same like mean, standard deviation, percentile, etc.

| acoustic_data | time_to_failure |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1.4690999832 |
| 6 | 1.4690999821 |

I want to group the data sequentially into chunks of some size. I am trying to figure out how to do the same using PySpark. Say the data was like below I can use `groupBy('idx')` to group them in chunks (of size 2 in this case).

| idx | acoustic_data | time_to_failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 1.4690999832 |
| 1 | 6 | 1.4690999821 |
| 2 | 12 | 1.4690999832 |
| 2 | 6 | 1.4690999821 |

So, when the chink size is 1000, the dataframe reads every 1000 entries and group them together. Is there a way to do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid moving the data to 1 partition you can use [`MONOTONICALLY_INCREASING_ID`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#monotonically_increasing_id).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

_data = [
    (12, 1.4690999832, ),
    (13, 1.4690999832, ),
    (14, 1.4690999832, ),
    (15, 1.4690999832, ),
]
_schema = ['acoustic_data', 'time_to_failure']
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, _schema)

group_expr = 'MONOTONICALLY_INCREASING_ID() DIV 1000'
df = df.withColumn('group', F.expr(group_expr))
df.show()

# +-------------+---------------+-------+
# |acoustic_data|time_to_failure|  group|
# +-------------+---------------+-------+
# |           12|   1.4690999832|      0|
# |           13|   1.4690999832|      0|
# |           14|   1.4690999832|8589934|
# |           15|   1.4690999832|8589934|
# +-------------+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your column 'idx' by adding a row number column (using row_number() and a window, but this is a bit slow), and then divide the row number by 1000 and round the result.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a natural way to partition your data, then you can use a window and partition by `F.lit(1)` so that everything is in one partition, and then create an index number. Then you divide each index number by your chunk size and round down. For example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (12, 1.22),
        (12, 1.42),
        (12, 1.55),
        (6, 1.33),
        (6, 1.42),
        (12, 2.53),
        (12, 2.24),
        (6, 0.97)
    ],
    schema=["acoustic_data","time_to_failure"]
)

bucket_size = 3

df_new = df.withColumn(
    'idx', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(F.lit(1)).orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())) - 1
).withColumn(
    'bucket',
    F.floor(F.col('idx') / bucket_size)
)
```

Then `df_new` will look like the following:

```
+-------------+---------------+---+------+
|acoustic_data|time_to_failure|idx|bucket|
+-------------+---------------+---+------+
|           12|           1.22|  0|     0|
|           12|           1.42|  1|     0|
|           12|           1.55|  2|     0|
|            6|           1.33|  3|     1|
|            6|           1.42|  4|     1|
|           12|           2.53|  5|     1|
|           12|           2.24|  6|     2|
|            6|           0.97|  7|     2|
+-------------+---------------+---+------+
```

Then you can groupby `bucket`, and calculate summary stats. As pointed out by @user2704177, this will be slow and you might run into performance issues for really large data sets. Pyspark is meant to be used on data that has a natural partitioning to it (i.e. data that can be divided up in some way by one of the columns).

Comment: this is basically sequential data and to generate the features I have to group them into chunks of 150000 entries.. the actual data has millions of entries.. do you have any suggestion what can be done to make it fast?

Comment: i would say that being able to partition your data in some way is the main reason that pyspark provides a performance boost. that being said, you might be able to use one of the built-in pyspark random functions to assign each row a bucket as long as you don't care about the data being split sequentially